# How do I test a .sample method in rspec?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am writing a test in rspec:

```
it "should choose a sign at random" do
  game.choose_sign
  expect(game.choose_sign).to eq "rock"
end
```

ruby code:

```
def choose_sign
  ["rock","paper","scissor"].sample
end
```

The code works but the test only passes when one of the values has been selected that matches whatever I put in the rspec test i.e. eq "rock"

How do I make it pass every time? This would be really useful to know for future reference when testing for random return values.

Comment: You can explicitly seed the random number generator using [`srand`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Kernel.html#method-i-srand).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can test that expected collection include result of your method:

```
it "chooses a random sign" do
  expect(["rock","paper","scissor"]).to include(game.choose_sign)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to test the logic rather than particular value being return. You can test for rerun value not being nil or not being empty. Sample method will return random value from array which will make harder for you to pass test everytime. Hope it helps.